# .Net. Why Garbage collector doesn't run when I clear a list?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I add 20 Mb to a list several times so that the application consumes 600MB. However why I clear the list, the memory isn't released.

Here is my code

```
List<int> data = new List<int>();
const int TwentyMB = 20 * 1024 * 1024;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void AddDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < TwentyMB; i++)
    {
        data.Add(i);
    }
}

private void DestroyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    data.Clear();
    data.Capacity = 0;
}
```

Until I call GC.Collect, the memory is released

```
private void CollectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the memory isn't release? When will GC work automatically?

Comment: I guess you should read [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sure. I have read that article I create this sample to verify what they said. I think it is stupid to waste 600 MB of memory. In a win form application, it may not cause any problem fo calling GC.Collect manually but in a asp.net site, it may affect the performance of other request.

Comment: Why should the memory be wasted? If the memory would be free, it would also be of no use.

Comment: It is not a "waste" of memory if nothing else needs it. At the point where something else needs it, it will be released. Don't forget that there is a cost in freeing up this memory in terms of time and processor cycles so it is not efficient to do it continually

Answer (score 2):

Because system is not in need of memory. GC works as seldom as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions that trigger garbage collection:

- The system has low physical memory.
- The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.
- The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

The Garbage collection time can vary depending on the machine it is running on and the resources available. in your case you can see that calling GC.Collect does in fact free up the memory, so there is nothing to worry about. If you wait for a few minutes after you clear the list you will probably see the same thing happening, but as I said this time can vary